# Enclosing a block of text in quotation marks (or any other couple of chars) in a csv

Tags: python, bash, pandas, csv, text

I have a .csv file, and I need to do what follows: for *each line*, starting from the *end* of the line, the text that occurs after a certain number of occurrences of a specified character should be enclosed in quotation marks.

I'll try and make myself clearer with an example. Consider the following line of a csv:

```
gentlemen, this is a block of text. Thanks!,1,0,0,1
```

I want to **enclose in quotation marks the slice of the line which occurs, starting from the end, after the fourth occurrence of a comma**. So, it should become:

```
"gentlemen, this is a block of text. Thanks!",1,0,0,1
```

I'd like to do it in bash, pure python, or pandas.

Comment: This is easy in pure python. Just loop from the end of the list down until your condition is met, keeping track of the index. The rest is just slicing. You can figure it out!

Comment: This question probably actually should have been flagged duplicate; it can't be the first question to ask "How do I match X in a string [before|after] Y number of Z, [forwards|backwards]." Also, one can get by with loops until one discovers regular expressions, then realizing that regexes are an expected part of a programmer's toolkit. The text on the down button is: "This question does not show any research effort: it is unclear or not useful." This isn't an insult. [Asking good SO questions is hard](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). 99% of users should really just have googled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In python:

```py
line = r'gentlemen, this is a block of text. Thanks!,1,0,0,1'
num_commas = 4
comma_count = 0
for c in reversed(line):
    from_end += 1
    if c == ',':
        comma_count += 1
    if comma_count >= num_commas:
        break
line[:-from_end]
# 'gentlemen, this is a block of text. Thanks!'
```

The rest is academic.

Answer (score 2):

With sed:

```
$ sed -E 's/(.*)((,.*){4})/"\1"\2/' <<< 'gentlemen, this is a block of text. Thanks!,1,0,0,1'
"gentlemen, this is a block of text. Thanks!",1,0,0,1
```

This uses two capture groups. The important part is `(,.*){4}`: these are four instances of a comma followed by anything. Because the first group matches greedily, the second group will match the last four commas on the line.

The substitution then puts double quotes around the first group and prints the second group unmodified.

Answer (score 0):

```python
In [1]: line = r'gentlemen, this is a block of text. Thanks!,1,0,0,1'
   ...: a,b,c,d,*e = line[::-1].split(",")
   ...: print((','.join([a,b,c,d])[::-1] + "," + "'" + ','.join(e) + "'")[::-1])
   ...: 
'gentlemen, this is a block of text. Thanks!',1,0,0,1
```